# ios private key and certificate not pairing

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning, keychain, private-key

I cannot seem to ge my certificate and private key to pair up in keychain access. They are both in keychain separately. Steps I have taken:

Clear everything from keychain
Import .p12 private key file (gives me warning saying contents of this item cannot be read)
Generate certificate request using this key (I have tried severally different emails - is this important?)
Upload request to provisioning profile
Refresh provisioning profiles under organizer in xcode which generates a team provisioning profile - this says cannot find valid private-key/certificate pair

I have created several certificates + provisioning profiles successfully in the past but this one seems to be putting up a fight.

This particular key was used for my old team provisioning profile but the certificate expired so I am trying to create a new certificate.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found an alternative way of submitting requests:

Revoke certificates in provisioning centre, delete profile from xcode. Then hit refresh in organizer in xcode, xcode will submit the request for you and do its stuff.

I was also missing a public key from the keychain which it generated.

Comment: JFoulkes, I wish I could give you a hug. I've been messing with the provisioning portal, obviously doing something wrong for the last 3 hours... this worked right away.